# Disable WiFi if LAN is connected

Tags: networking, wireless

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 some days ago. Most things work very fine.

But if I am connected via LAN, I get the warning again and again that WiFi can't connect.

This does not make sense.

If I have LAN, then I don't need WiFi.

Of course I can disable it by hand, but an automation which works be default would be fine.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Related to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/487640/disable-wifi-on-connection-to-ethernet-with-networkmanager and https://superuser.com/questions/233448/disable-wlan-if-wired-cable-network-is-available

Answer (score 24, accepted):

from manpage of Ubuntu for `nmcli-examples` https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man7/nmcli-examples.7.html Example 14. there is a script to make Ethernet and Wi-Fi mutually exclusive

```
#!/bin/bash
export LC_ALL=C

enable_disable_wifi ()
{
    result=$(nmcli dev | grep "ethernet" | grep -w "connected")
    if [ -n "$result" ]; then
        nmcli radio wifi off
    else
        nmcli radio wifi on
    fi
}

if [ "$2" = "up" ]; then
    enable_disable_wifi
fi

if [ "$2" = "down" ]; then
    enable_disable_wifi
fi
```

> ```
>    This dispatcher script makes Wi-Fi mutually exclusive with wired networking. When a wired
>    interface is connected, Wi-Fi will be set to airplane mode (rfkilled). When the wired
>    interface is disconnected, Wi-Fi will be turned back on. Name this script e.g.
>    70-wifi-wired-exclusive.sh and put it into /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/ directory.
>    See NetworkManager(8) manual page for more information about NetworkManager dispatcher
>    scripts.
> ```

Make the new script executable: `chmod a+rx /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/70-wifi-wired-exclusive.sh`

Comment: It would be very cool if Ubuntu would support this out-of-the-box.

Comment: Hi..have you tried to create the script as mentioned in Example 14 under the directory `etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d`

Comment: No, I have not tried it yet. Maybe someone has a more user friendly solution.

Comment: Yes, this script works fine. I updated your answer because there were leading spaces. Thank you! Nevertheless I think it makes sense to enable this by default.

Comment: This script fails if I unplug the LAN if the laptop is locked. If I start again from "sleep" mode, then it does not enable WLAN automatically. This needs to be done by hand :-(

Comment: The scripts works like a charm but be careful to the language set in your system. In my italian settings I had to grep for "collegato" instead of "connected"

Comment: @Manticore it works in non-English language because of the `export LC_ALL=C` at top.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 23.04 (in german language) I had to modify PRATAP's answer a tiny bit as it would not work.
I changed

> ```
> enable_disable_wifi ()
> {
>    result=$(nmcli dev | grep "ethernet" | grep -w "connected")
>    if [ -n "$result" ]; then
>        nmcli radio wifi off
>    else
>        nmcli radio wifi on
>    fi
> }
> ```

to

```
enable_disable_wifi ()
{
    found_eth=$(nmcli dev | grep "ethernet")
    eth_disconn=$(nmcli dev | grep "ethernet" | grep -w "nicht verbunden")
    if [ -n "$found_eth" ] && [ -z "$eth_disconn" ]; then
        nmcli radio wifi off
    else
        nmcli radio wifi on
    fi
}
```

and now it works. (I also had to change the owner of the .sh-file to root (found that in the networkmanager-dispatcher man pages) in addition to making it executeable.)
I'm not totally sure why but suspect it didn't work before as "verbunden" (i.e. "connected") is a word that is part of "nicht verbunden" (i.e. "disconnected").

Don't now if this is still relevant but I thought I'd share it.

Comment: Make it international like this: `result=$(LANG=C nmcli dev | grep "ethernet" | grep -w "connected")` or even:
`if LANG=C nmcli dev | grep -q '\sethernet\s\+connected\s'; then `